# Newbie: Use Android intents privately?

Tags: android

I'm a Java pro but an Android newbie, working through the NotePad example.  It uses Intents to work with an *internal* EditText.  Is this just for show, or is it considered a best practice to do this?  In ordinary Java, I would instantiate and work with an EditText directly.  This seems to say:

> I want to edit this note, I have my own internal editor, but I'm going
>   to ask the operating system if there are any editors out there, and
>   then hope it finds mine.

So, should I just instantiate EditText directly for a case like this in the real world?

Comment: What part of the code are you specifically referring to?

Comment: Specifically, I was referring to the intent filters in the manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really dont care about other apps using your activities and don't plan on publishing your intents to the world (ie. other apps on the phone). Then you can just use this

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityToOpen.class);
startActivity(i);
```

That's all. No fancy intent selectors or otherwise.

Comment: Note that you can do this even if you do export ActivityToOpen, allowing other applications to start it 'directly'. And to reiterate: this is not just for show, this is Android.

Comment: @JulianFondren if `ActivityToOpen` is not in the same package as you, then you cannot "call" it this way I've shown above. You would have to do it via action intents and in the manifest there would be intent filters to handle this.

Comment: Sure.  My comment addressed your phrasing, which suggests that an app cannot send an intent to one of its own activities in this manner if that activity is also receptive to foreign intents.

Comment: @JulianFondren I see what you mean. I agree. It was not my intention to imply that. Above code would work regardless of whether the activity has intent filters in the manifest or not.

Answer (score 1):

In *ordinary* Java (as you say it), we usually manage our application per-process, whether our process is running, or is it terminated, etc.

However, in Android, we need to think our application as a number of Activities, where one activity stands for one screen. It's because our application can be started on any activity, not just the first/main one.

That's why, when you're going to edit a note, you're suggested to use an Intent to launch *another* activity that handles the editing, using Intent *extras* to pass data between one activity to another activity. It's very common in Android and that's the right way to do it. Moreover, normally you can't access the `EditText` on another activity from one activity.

And no,

> I want to edit this note, I have my own internal editor, but I'm going to ask the operating system if there are any editors out there, and then hope it finds mine.

That's not correct. You still explicitly say in your intent that you want to start a new activity in *your own* package, not others.